# Getting Browser size using HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button and When its clicked it calls an alert that gets the browser size but it just says undefined x undefined. If I remove the function part then it will work correctly. How do i get it to work with the button click?

```
<input type="button" onclick="alertME()" value="Finish">

<script>

function alertME() 
{
alert (screen.width + 'x' + screen.height);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? The above code works in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Check this http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting the undefined message, did you open the file with firefox? If so which version? I know mine works fine with this code (v17) In older versions screen probably isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<input type="button" onclick="alertME()" value="Finish">

<script>

function alertME() 
{
var width = document.body.offsetWidth;
var height = document.body.offsetHeight;
alert (width + 'x' + height);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me on jsFiddle:

```
var width = screen.width;
var height = screen.height;

window.alertME = function()
{
    alert(width + 'x' + height);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="alertME();" value="Finish">
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting the undeafsfined message,asf did you open the file with firefox? If so which versafdsgion? I know minedadg works fine with this code (v17) In older versiodagadgns screen probably isn't supported.dfkjngdojsndosgdg